# Windows explorer stuck at "items remaining: 0" when copying files

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-explorer

This is a simple issue that I haven't found a fix for months and Google searching is futile.

Sometimes if I copy/move/delete large folders containing many files (think tens of thousands) using Windows Explorer it will freeze at "items remaining: 0" for several minutes, there are 0 items remaining but the remaining size is not 0.

Now before you think I am illiterate in computers I will tell you what I have verified that aren't the cause of the problem:

The disk in question is a hard disk device and its model is Seagate Exos ST4000NM000A, advertised as 4TB with capacity of 3725.29GiB.

It isn't an external hard drive and it is connected to the motherboard directly via a SATA 3.0 cable, and it is connected to the power supply via the power bus.

There are no bad sectors whatsoever, I have just checked today again using DiskGenius, and there are no problems whatsoever:

[image]

I/O speeds are typical of HDDs:

[image]

It passes SeaTools S.M.A.R.T. check, short drive self test, and short generic test without problems:

[image]

And its S.M.A.R.T. info looks good:

[image]

And the filesystem is in perfect condition:

```
PS C:\Users\Xeni> chkdsk D:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is Tremillia.

WARNING!  /F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  2247424 file records processed.
File verification completed.
 Phase duration (File record verification): 18.39 seconds.
  1231 large file records processed.
 Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.00 milliseconds.
  0 bad file records processed.
 Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 0.36 milliseconds.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  7547 reparse records processed.
  2425048 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
 Phase duration (Index verification): 2.47 minutes.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
 Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 8.50 seconds.
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
 Phase duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 0.22 milliseconds.
  7547 reparse records processed.
 Phase duration (Reparse point and Object ID verification): 36.70 milliseconds.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
 Phase duration (Security descriptor verification): 18.73 milliseconds.
  88813 data files processed.
 Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 1.05 milliseconds.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  122221832 USN bytes processed.
Usn Journal verification completed.
 Phase duration (USN journal verification): 1.94 seconds.

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

   3813878 MB total disk space.
   2740949 MB in 1404514 files.
    597304 KB in 88814 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
   2552718 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
1095530152 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 976353019 total allocation units on disk.
 273882538 allocation units available on disk.
Total duration: 2.95 minutes (177477 ms).
```

What then, can be the cause of this annoying problem? Why sometimes copying large folders will cause Windows explorer to freeze at "items remaining: 0"? Google searching yields absolutely nothing relevant.

The only thing I can think of is write caching, so I opened `devmgmt.msc` and sure enough, the write caching policy for all disks is set to on by default:

[image]

Is write-caching related to this problem? Should I disable write-caching? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It is normal for this to happen. It is simply writing the cache and waiting for that to complete so you are not shutting down the computer. Just wait for it to finish.

Comment: Explorer is very slow on copying.

Comment: You can use Process Monitor to view exactly what it is doing when it is getting stuck. I recommend you do that.